# Copy ssh files from ubuntu to Mac and access denied to github

Tags: git, ssh

I am copying my ssh file id_rsa.pub from my ubuntu machine to my mac os x lion. But when i run `ssh -T git@github.com` it just shows me the access denied message.

any help on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *private* key is stored in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. id_rsa.pub is just the public key that everyone knows. Copying the private key to your Mac machine should be sufficient.

You can also just [generate a new key](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) and register the *public* part of it in your [github ssh settings](https://github.com/settings/ssh).